# Is there anyway to shorten this Java code by validating name and weight using only one do...while?

Tags: java, validation, input

Is there any way to validate name(String) and weight(double) in only one do while?
How to add optional regex such as [./ ] besides [a-zA-Z]+  ?

```
do {
                System.out.print("Name: ");
                name = input.nextLine();
                if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", name)) {

                isValid = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input\nPlease try again\n");

                isValid = false;

            }
        } while (!(isValid));
do {
            System.out.print("Height(cm): ");
            input.nextLine();

            if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
                height = input.nextDouble();
                if (height > 5 && height <= 500) {
                    isValid = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input\nPlease try again\n");
                    isValid = false;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input\nPlease try again\n");
                isValid = false;
            }
        } while (!(isValid));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the optional regular expression `[./ ]` into the same pattern separated by `|`. Validation in a single do-while can be performed like this:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StackOverflow
{    
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  Boolean isNameValid = false, isHeightValid = false;
  String name = null; double height = 0;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+|[./ ]");
 
  do
  {  
   if(!isNameValid)
   {
     System.out.print("Name: ");
     name = input.nextLine();
     Matcher match = pattern.matcher(name);
     if (match.find()) 
        isNameValid = true;
     else
     {
        System.out.println("Invalid input\nPlease try again\n");
        isNameValid = false;
     }
   }
   if(isNameValid && !isHeightValid)    
   {
      System.out.print("Height(cm): ");
      if (input.hasNextDouble())
      {
         height = input.nextDouble();
         if (height > 5 && height <= 500)
            isHeightValid = true;
         else 
         {
            System.out.println("Invalid input\nPlease try again\n");
            isHeightValid = false;
         }
      } 
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Invalid input\nPlease try again\n");
         isHeightValid = false;
      }
   }
  }while(!(isNameValid)||!(isHeightValid));
  
  input.close();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Boolean validName = false, validWeight = false;
    do {
        if(!validName) {
            //get and validate weight
            // when found the correct name; set validName to true
        }
        if(validName && !validWeight) {
            //get and validate weight
        }
    }while(validName && validWeight);
```

If there are more than two such validations you can wrap each read-validate in a function.